# npm run watch is showing error in laravel

Tags: laravel, command-prompt

when i use npm run watch or npm run watch-poll it shows me these errrors

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\UwAmp\www\mover\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\UwAmp\www\mover\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-18T04_29_33_252Z-debug.log
```

my npm version is 6.14.4 and node version is 14.2.0

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the path containing package.json doesn't exists. Put the right path on. It will work.

Comment: Check package.json file is missing or not.